# Error in program-censor(codecademy)Practice makes perfect

Tags: python

I wanted to include spaces too while splitting the text, for that i looked up on google used import re

```
import re
def censor(text,word) :
    text1=re.split(r"(\s+)",text)
    #print text1
    sum=""
    for i in range(0,len(text1)) :
        if text1[i]==word :
            for j in range(0,len(word)) :
                sum=sum+"*"
        else :
            sum=sum+text[i]
    return sum
```

The error I am getting is

[image displaying error and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTIvu.png)

If I include an another for loop to replace every 'e' with a whitespace , it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `text1` (very bad naming BTW) is a list of words, and `text` a single string. Your first `for` loop is iterating on `text1` indices (words in the list), but in the `else` clause you subscript the whole `text` string. Obviously you want to get the word from the words list (`text1`), not the character at position `i` in the `text` string. IOW: replace your `else` clause with:

```
sum=sum+text1[i]
```

and the test should pass.

If you used a correct naming and proper code layout you would certainly have spotted the problem more easily:

```
def censor(text, word) :
    words = re.split(r"(\s+)",text)
    sum=""
    for i in range(0, len(words)) :
        if words[i] == word :
            for j in range(0, len(word)) :
                sum = sum + "*"
        else :
            # here you easily spot the error
            sum = sum + text[i]

    return sum
```

Also you are making things much more complicated than they have to be. You can pre-compute the "replacement" string for "bad" words once for all before the loop (and you don't need a loop to do so), and you don't need a `range` and indexed acces, ou can iterate directly on the words list instead:

```
def censor(text, word) :
    replacement = "*" * len(word)
    words = re.split(r"(\s+)", text)
    cleaned = ""
    for w in words :
        if w == word :
            cleaned += replacement 
        else :
            cleaned += w
    return cleaned
```

There would be other possible improvements but at least this is mostly readable and much more pythonic.